# Deep Linking inside WebView in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, webview, deep-linking

I'm trying to use Amazon Cognito oauth2 in my Xamarin application but I have a problem.

I have this code to open my URL inside the WebView :

```
var browser = new WebView
{
    Source = "https://[domain].auth.[region].amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=[client_id]&response_type=code&redirect_uri=myapplication://home&scope=[scope]"
}
Content = browser;
```

I'm able to load the page in the WebView but, when the WebView tries to load the redirect_uri (**myapplication://home**) I got an Android Error Page "WebPage not available" with the error : net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME.

Also, When I'm using `Device.OpenUri([my_uri])` everything works well.

I'm using Android 8.0 to test my application.

Comment: Override `ShouldOverrideUrlLoading` and test if your link is being received and the you can create an Intent and start your new Activity

Comment: I already override `OnAppLinkRequestReceived` inside my `App.xaml.cs` file but it isn't call  when I'm using the WebView

Comment: I am talking about Android's WebView

Comment: The function `ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)` is never called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved my issue by adding this code before `Content = browser` :

```
browser.Navigating += async (s, e) =>
{
    if (e.Url.StartsWith("myapplication://home"))
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri(e.Url);
        ((App)(Application.Current)).NavigateToLoginPage(uri);
    }
};
```

`NavigateToLoginPage(Uri uri)` is just a basic function that change the MainPage in `App.xaml.cs`